# Recording time of "X" amount of indicators in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, time, record

I have 600 different stocks I am recording, different BUY/SELL ratings, and I have this macro to run through and record -on average- how many seconds it takes for each stock. This is nice and works but now I am wanting to see how long it takes for a group of 20 stocks. I would like to be able to record 20 amount of stocks, record how long it took each stock. I need this macro to go through all 600 stocks while recording how long it took to record 20 amount of stocks. How do I get the macro to tell me how long it took to run through 20 of the 600 times? I want the value of the time to start in "C30" and then each next value would be offset 1 cell down

```
'
' Repeat Macro
'
'
Start = Timer

  Dim i As Integer
  
For i = 1 To 600

  Call Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinDown
  DoEvents
  Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"
  DoEvents
  Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"
  DoEvents
  Call CopyPaste
  DoEvents

Next i

ElapsedTime = Format((Timer - Start) / (86400 * 600), "hh: mm: ss: ms ")
Range("C30").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = ElapsedTime


    MsgBox "Indicators have been updated.", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for. I suggest adding a sheet reference `Cells`.

I made the divisor a variable so you don't forget to change the value in the offset calculation if you modify the value.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim start As Long
    Dim groupval as long
    groupval = 20 'Change this to change the group size
    start = Timer
    For i = 1 To 600

        Call Sheet4.SpinButton1_SpinDown
        DoEvents
        Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"
        DoEvents
        Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"
        DoEvents
        Call CopyPaste
        DoEvents
  
        If i Mod groupval = 0 Then
            Cells(30, 3).Offset((i / groupval) - 1).Value = Format((Timer - start) / (86400 * 600), "hh: mm: ss: ms ")
            start = Timer
        End If
  
    Next i

    MsgBox "Indicators have been updated.", vbOKOnly


End Sub
```

Comment: You are the best! Works flawlessly